# must match query not working as expected in Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, aws-elasticsearch

I've created my index below using Kibana which connected to my AWS ES domain:

```
PUT sals_poc_test_20210217-7
{
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 10,
        "number_of_replicas" : 1,
        "max_result_window": 50000,
        "max_rescore_window": 50000
      }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "identifier": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "CLASS_NAME": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "CLIENT_ID": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

then I've indexed 100 documents, using below command returns all 100 documents:

```
POST /sals_poc_test_20210217-7/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_index": "sals_poc_test_20210217-7"
    }
  }
}
```

two sample documents are below:

```
{
        "_index" : "sals_poc_test_20210217-7",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "cd0a3723-106b-4aea-b916-161e5563290f",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "identifier" : "xweeqkrz",
          "class_name" : "/Sample_class_name_1",
          "client_id" : "random_str"
        }
      },
{
        "_index" : "sals_poc_test_20210217-7",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "cd0a3723-106b-4aea-b916-161e556329ab",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "identifier" : "xweeqkra",
          "class_name" : "/Sample_class_name_2",
          "client_id" : "random_str_2"
        }
      }
```

but when I wanted to search by `CLASS_NAME` by below command:

```
POST /sals_poc_test_20210217-7/_search
{
  "size": 200,
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "must": [ 
        { "match": { "CLASS_NAME": "/Sample_class_name_1"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Not only the documents that match this `class_name` returned, but also other ones.

Anyone could shed any light into this case please?

I'm suspecting the way I wrote my search query is problematic. But cannot figure out why.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic search, is case sensitive. class_name is not equal to CLASS_NAME sample documents seems to have `class_name` but mapping in index seems to have 'CLASS_NAME.

If we `GET sals_poc_test_20210217-7`, both class name attributes should be in the index mapping. The one when creating the index and second one created when adding documents to index.

so, query should be on CLASS_NAME or class_name.keyword , by default elastic search creates both text and .keyword field for dynamic attributes

```
    "CLASS_NAME" : {
      "type" : "keyword"
    },

    "class_name" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Nice, I was able to search and get correct results by using `class_name.keyword`, but not `CLASS_NAME`, any suggestions as of how to tweek the query so that I could use `CLASS_NAME` to search? thanks!

Comment: is there a reason you have both attributes CLASS_NAME and class_name? if your data has class_name, it may be better to create index with lower case class_name in mapping. if you have both, then create both attributes in mapping as keyword and we can modify the query to search against both attributes with OR condition

Comment: Perfect, I got it working with only lowercase `class_name` now, and searching by `class_name` returns me correct results, thanks a ton!